# Custom UITableViewCell not showing labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I've created custom cell view in Xcode:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let iniStr = self.tableArray[indexPath.row]

        let fullNameArr = iniStr.components(separatedBy: "||1||")
        let daFirst = fullNameArr[0]
        let daSecond = fullNameArr[1]

        let finalco = daSecond.components(separatedBy: "||2||")
        let fString = finalco[0]

        cell.questionLabel?.text = daFirst
        cell.answerLabel?.text = daSecond

        return cell
    }

class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

}
```

then hooked up everything in storyboard, set constraints and registered class: `self.tableView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`

When I use Subtitle as class of my custom table cell everything works fine, but when I use custom FeedCell in my table cell, label's are not showing, but I am able to select cells.

Comment: Have you created a separate xib file for `FeedCell`? Since you mention storyboard in your question, I'm guessing that the UI for the cell is placed directly within your controller. In that case, you don't need to call `self.tableView.register`.

Comment: @ØyvindHauge no, I'm not created, I don't even know how to.

Comment: check if have confirmed to UITableViewDataSource and then check if numberOfRowsInSection returning correct number of rows

Comment: `self.tableView.delegate = self / self.tableView.dataSource = self` and numberOfRowsInSection returning correct number

Comment: use breakpoint in cellforRow to verify the values self.tableArray at the index or just try dummy values to check if it is setting the values correctly for cell

Comment: what was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to debug connections

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let iniStr = self.tableArray[indexPath.row]
        print(iniStr)

        let fullNameArr = iniStr.components(separatedBy: "||1||")
        let daFirst = fullNameArr[0]
        let daSecond = fullNameArr[1]
        print(daFirst)
        print(daSecond)

        let finalco = daSecond.components(separatedBy: "||2||")
        let fString = finalco[0]

        cell.questionLabel?.text = daFirst
        cell.answerLabel?.text = daSecond

        cell.questionLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.answerLabel.backgroundColor = .green




        return cell

    }
```

Comment: what is <nibName>?

Comment: xib name of custom cell.

Comment: OP mentions that he has "hooked everything in storyboard", which implies that he is not using a separate layout file for his custom cell. Hence, `register` is not needed.

Comment: Now I'm not using neither xib nor register, but labels still not show

Comment: Oh. my bad. !! 

@MrJo then make sure you have given cellIdentifier in storyboard for cell. This also cause problem.

Comment: I see that cells are imported and clickable but without text

Comment: @MrJo try to debug with changing colors of labels. You must see atleast two labels in cells. if not then there may be issue in connections. check if IBOutlets are properly connected to cell rather than view controller. I have update my answer above for debug

Comment: My Pleasure any time @MrJo :)